# Increment last number in string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

given the following string:

```
Backticks[0].Folders[0]
```

I need to increment the latter number.

I'm not an expert with Regexp replacements, I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uVBWB/) but it also selects the bracket.

```
href = href.replace(/\d+]$/gi, matchedNumber++);
```

Is it possible to do the selection, incremental and replacement in a one liner?

Comment: `.` will match any character except a line break. Escape it to match a literal `.`, like `\.`.

Comment: @squint, no, the above regex matches `0]`.

Comment: @squint You misunderstand, he wants to match the number right before the end of the string, but the problem is that he's also including it in the match so it gets replaced out of existence.

Comment: @Patashu: I'm just explaining what a `.` does in a regex.

Comment: @Shimmy: That's exactly what I'm saying. It'll match almost any character, which means it'll match the `]`.

Comment: @Squint You are correct, but he knows what `.` does, evidenced by the fact that he's using it correctly.

Comment: @Patashu: It's a matching character. If OP was expecting it to exclude what it matched from the result, then he wasn't using it correctly.

Comment: @squint Newbies to regex don't know how to expect a character to exist around a match without including it in the match and thus replacing it too. It's not an obvious thing to solve (since you need either lookarounds or noncapturing groups)

Comment: @Patashu: Or just a capturing group to get the number. Since the character after it is known, it can just be put into the result. `/(\d+)]$/` I didn't say it was obvious to solve. Not too tough though either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It **is** possible to do in one line

```
'Ace[0].Folders[0]'.replace(/\d+(?=]$)/, function(i) { return parseInt(i) + 1; })
```

Comment: Wow, that's crazy that you can pass a regex a function like that! Cool!

Comment: Can I place a `var i = 0` before your line, to reset counter?

Comment: @Shimmy: to reset it to what? Do you understand how `replace` and its callback work?

Comment: Now I think I got it, `i` represents the number to be replaced.

Comment: @Shimmy: right, and the argument equals to the current match number

Comment: So I got it right. Thank you! This is a rocking answer. It revealed to me an interesting aspect I didn't know exists. So is this because the `replace` function has an overload that expects a delegate?

Comment: @Shimmy: it's not actually an overload - it's the same implementation that accepts multiple optional arguments, since in js there are no functions overloading.

Answer (score 1):

Use a positive lookahead:

```
/\d(?=]$)/gi
```

This will make sure there is any character after then the end of string after the digit, without including it in the replace.

If you would like to increment it, you could use `match` and `parseInt`:

```
var href = this.href;
var re = /\d(?=.$)/gi
href = href.replace(re, parseInt(href.match(re))+1);
```

[Here is a page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) where you can learn more about this.

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/uVBWB/6/)

Comment: @Patashu thanks, I was about to make that edit when it said "an edit was made!" :P

Comment: @Doorknob, now to the incrementatal, how do I do that? Can I do it with regex?

Comment: @Shimmy It's extremely unlikely that you could do it with a regex. It's not what a regex is designed to do. Capture the number, increment it by one and reconstruct the string.